# Create a copy of a directory that contains all the files with the correct names, but no files have any data in them?

Tags: windows-8.1, filesystems

For a python project I'm working on, which involves renaming many gigabytes of files, I require an identical directory on which I can test the program. The issue is, I don't want to be copying this directory every time the program doesn't work properly. So my idea is to mirror the directory somewhere else, but without having any data in the files (asides from metadata, as this is an important part of the project).

Is there any program or windows (8.1) function that can do this, or will I have to write a program instead?

Comment: I'd probably write a python script to do it. just use os.walk on the source, and for every file, create a new one in the destination hierarchy with the same name. that should give you 0-byte files, replicating your hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The program Robycopy could be a solutions for you. 
With the command bellow, Robocopy creates a directory tree structure containing zero-length files only (that is, no file data is copied) and does the entire directory

Robocopy SourceDir DestDir /CREATE /MIR

The GUI have loads of good tooltips for all the flags to the command.

I use the Command Line GUI version of Robycopy that I've downloaded from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/commandlinegui/)

"Updated from Comments"

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to get it to copy id3 tags?

Comment: Not entirely sure if bellow would work. It tells it to copy DATA ATTRIBUTES TIMESTAMP
Robocopy SourceDir DestDir /COPY:DAT /CREATE

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, Datmocc, and I'm not sure what Data it did actually copy. In the end I used `Robocopy SourceDir DestDir /MIR /CREATE`, because /MIR does the entire directory tree instead of just the specified file. I will probably use mp3tag to copy the metadata. Ta